# Second order differential equation by linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve the following differential equations $\frac {du}{dt} = Au$ and $\frac {d^2u}{dt^2} = Au$ with 
$$
A = 
        \begin{bmatrix}
        -2 & 1 & 0 \\
        1 & -2 & 1 \\
        0 & 1 & -2 \\
        \end{bmatrix},
$$

$u(0) = (0, 2 \sqrt 2, 0)$ and $\frac{du}{dt}(0) = 0$

by linear algebra. I get the complete solution for the first equation and get stuck on the second one. The textbook ("Introduction to Linear Algebra" by Strang) offers the following solution:

*$\frac {d^2u}{dt^2} = Au$ has the same eigenvectors  x.  But  now the eigenvalues  $\lambda$ lead to oscillations $e^{i\omega t}x$ and $e^{-i\omega t}x$.  The  frequencies  come  from $\omega^2 = -\lambda$.*

Then it proceeds to plug $e^{i\omega t}x$ into the second order equation to show the last equation holds. My question is:

Is there a specific method for solving this kind of second order equation relying on $e^{i\omega t}x$? Or am I missing something and there actually is a way to deduce $e^{i\omega t}x$ from what is asked? Needles to say, at this point in the material, specific methods for solving the second equation have not been covered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can solve the second order system by thinking of it as a larger first order system.  In particular, define $v = \frac{du}{dt}$.  We can rewrite your one matrix equation as a "system of matrix equations", namely
$$
\frac {du}{dt} = v\\
\frac{dv}{dt} = Au
$$
We can write the whole thing with one matrix using block matrices.  In particular, we have
$$
\frac{d}{dt} \pmatrix{u\\v} = \pmatrix{0&I\\A&0}
$$
That is, if we let $x$ denote the column-vector $(u_1,u_2,u_3,v_1,v_2,v_3)$, then our linear differential equation is $\frac {dx}{dt} = Mx$, where 
$$
M = \pmatrix{
0&0&0&1&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&1&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&1\\
-2 & 1 & 0 &0&0&0\\
1 & -2 & 1 &0&0&0\\
0 & 1 & -2 &0&0&0\\
}
$$
with the initial condition $x(0) = (0,2\sqrt{2},0,0,0,0)$.  You should be able to take it from there on your own and reach the desired conclusion by rote.

---

If we want to figure out *why* those new eigenvalues should satisfy that equation, suppose that $\omega$ is an eigenvalue of $M$, and $y$ is an eigenvector.  Split $y$ up into the two vectors of length $3$ $y_1$ and $y_2$.  note that
$$
My = \omega y \implies\\
\pmatrix{0&I\\A&0}\pmatrix{y_1\\y_2} = \omega\pmatrix{y_1\\y_2} \implies\\
\pmatrix{y_2\\ Ay_1} = \pmatrix{\omega y_1\\ \omega y_2}
$$
With this system of equations, we should be able to deduce that $y_1$ satisfies $Ay_1 = \omega^2 y_1$.  That is, $\omega^2$ should be an eigenvalue of $A$.